# How to integrate SAP UI5 application to Apache Cordova for Mobile platform

Tags: eclipse, cordova, sapui5

I am trying to integrate SAP UI 5 application to mobile application, for this I am working with Apache Cordova.

1. Created a sample application in Eclipse Luna which is having SAP UI5 Plugin
2. Created a sample Apache Cordova Application using Windows CLI
3. Copied the webcontent files from SAP UI 5 application to www folder of cordova application
4. Added Android Platform
5. Build the application

Now while running the app in mobile device, I am getting white blank page. I am not sure what's the problem is ? Can someone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience Wherever you built the application doesn't matter.!
You can create an Apache cordova project first then,copy the **SAPUI5 Resource folder** under www folder with your application files.The Resource folder which will be holding all the libraries which is mandatory to support SAPUI5 controls.

Also keep your Resource folder path in you index.html file in your project.

Then next step you try to build your application using CLI or Command prompt with Cordova standard commands.

I hope this will help you..!

Cheers.